# Surroundings work on piston-cylinder arrangement

Tags: thermodynamics

While calculating the work of a system consisting of a piston-cylinder arrangement, textbooks always use absolute pressure, which eliminates the effect of atmospheric pressure on the outside of the piston, why is that? shouldn't we use gauge pressure instead?

Comment: To apply the ideal gas law (or other equation of state), it is necessary to use the absolute pressure.  But, if there is atmospheric pressure acting on the outside of the piston, it needs to be included in the force balance on the piston.

Comment: So what you are saying that the textbooks (e.g Yunus Cengel) consider the surroundings to be total vacuum?

Comment: Maybe.  Can you provide some actual context?  I've sometimes posed problems in thermo where the cylinder is in a vacuum chamber.

Comment: In Yunus Cengel: 4.1
"the boundary work in the differential form is equal to the product
of the absolute pressure P and the differential change in the volume dV of
the system. This expression also explains why the moving boundary work is
sometimes called the P dV work"

Comment: Sonntag also said the same idea but in different expression. And all the following examples say the same idea that they only use absolute pressure with no mentioning of atmospheric pressure, it is only mentioned when they discussed the concept of exergy (Availability) in a later chapter

Comment: In the quote you  cite, the assumption is that the external pressure applied to (the outside face of) the piston is P, while the pressure that the gas exerts on (the inside face of) the piston is slightly higher at P+dP, so that the piston is able to slowly move and the work done by the gas on its surroundings (the piston) is PdV.  In order to use the ideal gas law to calculate this total work, you need to take the integral of $PdV=\frac{nRT}{V}dV$.  Once the ideal gas law is employed, the pressure that is required is the absolute pressure.

Comment: If we considered the pressure inside the cylinder to be higher by differential amount, wouldn't this make only the differential amount to exert work instead of the pressure of the gas (dP*dV), also what if the pressure of the gas was much higher than the outside pressure due to the weight of the piston?

Comment: We are only interested in the work that the gas does on the piston, and not the net amount of work done on the piston.  (Certainly, as you say, the net amount of work done on the piston by the combination of the gas and the external pressure is zero).  Also, for the present, we are assuming a massless piston.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your concern is on the piston, you will need to consider both pressures. But when your study object is the gas inside the cylinder, atmospheric pressure is irrelevant.